# how to prevent multiple jumps using isGrounded properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a First-Person game using the new input system. The issue I'm facing is jumping. when I press `Space` to jump, I can jump again while the player is still in the air, I can jump multiple times till the player fly. This should not happen. the player should jump only when he is grounded.

```
public class MyPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private InputMaster controls;
    private float moveSpeed = 8f;
    private float runSpeed = 50f;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float gravity = -9.8f;
    private Vector2 move;
    private float run;
    private float jumpHeight = 2.4f;
    private CharacterController controller;
    public Transform ground;
    public float distanceToGround = 0.4f;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundMask;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool isRunning; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new InputMaster();
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        controls.Player.Run.started += _ => isRunning = true;
        controls.Player.Run.canceled += _ => isRunning = false;
    }
     void Update()
    {
        Grav();
        PlayerMovement();
        Jump(); 
        // check if Run button is pressed
        if (isRunning)
        {
            run = controls.Player.Run.ReadValue<float>();
            Vector3 running = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
            controller.Move(running * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void PlayerMovement() 
    {
        move = controls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Vector3 movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
        controller.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Jump() 
    {
        if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity); 
        }
    }

    public void OnRun()
    {
        isRunning = !isRunning;
    }

    private void Grav() 
    {
        //handeling gravity
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, distanceToGround, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        { 
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable(); 
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable(); 
    }
}
```

I tried to fix this issue by changing the jump condition to this :

```
if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered && isGrounded)
```

but now the player does not jump at all. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't given the player's GameObject the Constant Force component, I would do it since it solves most of the issue right away, and whenever I try to implement a jumping mechanic for the player I just go into whatever script controls their movement, and if I chose the space bar to be the jump button I would write the following

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
```

I would add the Constant Force component to the player's GameObject, and it will also add the rigid body component automatically which is where you can control the mass of the player, and along with the line of code above, should make it so the player can't spam jump and fly away

Comment: No, I didn't apply Force to my player, can you please include the right way of adding it?

Comment: I see so it can be added in the inspector itself. I added the constant force but how do I know the values currently, it is all zeros. should I check/uncheck anything in  the rigidbody?

Comment: No you should leave it as is for this problem, but once you add the component and check for the key you want to be the jump button and move it up, it should be all you need

Comment: No, the problem isn't solved by adding the constant force and the line you wrote. The player still flies